# Let $A$ be a commutative ring with identity. Prove a proper ideal $M \subsetneq A$ is maximal if and only if $A/M$ is simple.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I do not understand how the fact $M$ is maximal is related to $A/M$ being simple.

Comment: If $I/M$ is a proper non-trivial ideal of $A/M$, what can you say about $\langle I, M \rangle$?

Comment: Provided $M$ is maximal, I can assure $\langle I, M\rangle = A$. Is that right?

Comment: Hint: Think of the correspondence isomorphism theorems. Specifically every proper ideal $J \leq A/M$ is of the form $I/M$ for some proper ideal $I$ of $A$ which contains $M$.

Comment: And can that be possible if $I/M$ is a proper, non-trivial ideal of $A/M$?

Comment: No, we previously stated $I/M$ is non trivial and because of that $I \neq M$. Also, $I \neq A$ because $I/M$ is a proper ideal. Contradiction.